# Java- store PDUs that are being read by my program in an ArrayList

Tags: java, while-loop, nullpointerexception

I have a Java method called `receivePdu()`, which will listen for any PDUs being sent across a network, and print out the entity ID, and location of each PDU in the simulation, in the console.
I am using a `while` loop to do this, so that my code is continually listening for PDUs for as long as it is running.

I now want to amend my code, so that as well as printing the information about each individual PDU in the console, it will also store that information in an ArrayList, so that it can be used by another Java class in my program.

My `receivePdu()` method currently looks like this:

```
public static void receivePdu(){

    try{
        /*Specify the socket to receive the data */
        socket = new MulticastSocket(EspduSender.PORT);
        address = InetAddress.getByName(EspduSender.DEFAULT_MULTICAST_GROUP);
        socket.joinGroup(address); 

        /*Loop infinitely, receiving datagrams */
        while(true){
            byte buffer[] = new byte[MAX_PDU_SIZE];
            packet = new DatagramPacket(buffer, buffer.length);

            socket.receive(packet);

            Pdu pdu = pduFactory.createPdu(packet.getData()); /*    Commented on 15/04/2014 @ 09:15 */

            if(pdu != null){
                System.out.print("Got PDU of type: " + pdu.getClass().getName());
                if(pdu instanceof EntityStatePdu){
                    EntityID eid = ((EntityStatePdu)pdu).getEntityID();
                    Vector3Double position = ((EntityStatePdu)pdu).getEntityLocation();
                    System.out.print(" EID:[" + eid.getSite() + ", " + eid.getApplication() + ", " + eid.getEntity() + "] ");
                    System.out.print(" Location in DIS coordinates: [" + position.getX() + ", " + position.getY() + ", " + position.getZ() + "]");
                } else if(!(pdu instanceof EntityStatePdu)){
                    System.out.println("There are no PDUs currently being received.");
                }
                System.out.println();
            }
        } /*end while */
    } /*end try */
    catch(Exception e){
        System.out.println(e);
        e.printStackTrace();
        System.out.println("This is where the error is being generated");
        /*09/04/2014 @ 17:100
         * If this exception gets called, presumably it either means that pdu is not an instance of EntityStatePdu, or
         * that pdu does not actually hold a packet.  */
    }
}
```

I have now added an `ArrayList` to my class (outside the `receivePdu()` method), using the line: `public static ArrayList<pdu> espdu;` and amended my while loop to add each PDU to the ArrayList:

```
/*Loop infinitely, receiving datagrams */
while(true){
    byte buffer[] = new byte[MAX_PDU_SIZE];
    packet = new DatagramPacket(buffer, buffer.length);

    socket.receive(packet);

    Pdu pdu = pduFactory.createPdu(packet.getData()); /*    Commented on 15/04/2014 @ 09:15 */

    if(pdu != null){
    System.out.print("Got PDU of type: " + pdu.getClass().getName());
    if(pdu instanceof EntityStatePdu){
    EntityID eid = ((EntityStatePdu)pdu).getEntityID();
    Vector3Double position = ((EntityStatePdu)pdu).getEntityLocation();
    System.out.print(" EID:[" + eid.getSite() + ", " + eid.getApplication() + ", " + eid.getEntity() + "] ");
    System.out.print(" Location in DIS coordinates: [" + position.getX() + ", " + position.getY() + ", " + position.getZ() + "]");
    espdu.add(pdu);
} else if(!(pdu instanceof EntityStatePdu)){
        System.out.println("There are no PDUs currently being received.");
}
System.out.println();
    }
} /*end while */
```

However, when I now run my code, although the first PDU that is received is displayed, I get a `java.lang.NullPointerException` where the line `espdu.add(pdu);` is being called- and it is complaining about that line: `espdu.add(pdu);`.

I don't understand why I'm getting the null pointer exception there- anyone have any ideas? I have declared the ArrayList with the rest of the variables at the top of the class, in the way mentioned above. Any help or guidance with this would be much appreciated.

Comment: Have you initialised the the `ArrayList` anywhere? `final List<Pdu> espdu = new ArrayList<Pdu>()`?

Comment: I declared it just outside the `receivePdu()` method, with the line `public static ArrayList<Pdu> espdu;`. Is that what you mean by initialise?

Comment: Looks my comment, do you use `new` anywhere. I don't see it...

Comment: Sorry- I had tried what I thought you suggested- but didn't see the `()` at the end of your comment- missed it on the next line. That's brilliant- works exactly as I'd hoped. Thanks very much!